# Implementation of simple, non-cryptographic hash functions

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I'm new to programming, and am struggling to figure out how to use simple hash functions.

For example, I put together the below code to test the RS Hashing function (in C), and I keep getting a segfault.

Perhaps I'm mis-implementing the function... I've tried a few other simple hash functions (e.g. PJW) and also got segfaults.

I did eliminate one of the function's original parameters (unsigned int length) (because I'm completing a problem set and the specification for our hash function is that it should only take a const string as input), but I thought that would be fine, since I *think* this parameter refers to the string length, which I can easily get using strlen inside of the function, instead of passing it to the function. I tried debugging using valgrind, but it's not showing me any leaking memory. Perhaps I'm missing some fundamental knowledge on how to incorporate external code into my own source code.

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Return error if string name missing from command line
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover.c string name\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i = hash(argv[2]);
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

unsigned int hash(const char *word) // RS Hashing function
{
    unsigned int b = 378551;
    unsigned int a = 63689;
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    unsigned int length = strlen(word);
    unsigned int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; word++, i++)
    {
        hash = hash * a + (*word);
        a = a * b;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight! It would be really helpful to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Hint: if `argc == 2`, the only usable indices of `argv` are 0 and 1.

Comment: what a stupid mistake. thanks for flagging!

Answer (score -1):

I believe @Mat already got it:

The segmentation fault is due to your argc condition. If you change the condition to (argc <= 2), you will avoid the segmentation fault. (https://onlinegdb.com/r1Udx0lYI)

In addition, if you are interested in "Implementation of simple, non-cryptographic hash functions", I invite you to take a look at the following website :

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html